# Pull from join with column conditional on table source

Tags: sql, join

I want to pull an SQL statement so that one column (not present in the second table) is conditionally filled based on table source.

```
Table1
joinid
flag1
cond1
cond2
date

Table2
joinid
flag2
cond2
date
```

I would like the output to be:

```
flag1,flag2,cond1,cond2
```

where cond1 is always 600 for results from table2.

there is a condition that the date must be in a specific range.

Psuedo Ex:

```
SELECT flag1,flag2,IF tablesource=table1 then cond1 else 600 AS cond1,cond2 
FROM table1 
WHERE date IN (date1,date2,date3, etc) 
LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.joinid=table2.joinid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you're looking for results from both tables in different rows.  That's accomplished with a `union` instead of a `left join`:

```
select  flag1
,       flag2
,       cond1
,       cond2
from    (
        select  flag1
        ,       null as flag2
        ,       cond1
        ,       cond2
        ,       date
        from    Table1
        union all
        select  null
        ,       flag2
        ,       600
        ,       cond2
        ,       date
        from    Table2
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   '2010-01-01' <= date and date < '2011-01-01'
```

Comment: So it'll have to be a union then? no way to do that with a join?

Comment: A join is used to return rows with columns from multiple tables.  You'd get a result set like `table1col1, table1col2, ..., table2col1, table2col2, ...`

Comment: Right. I didn't think about that. A union would work best for me then. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Do the two cond2 fields need to be put into one target field? 
Which date field needs to be used for the filter?

Assuming no and table1...

SELECT 
t1.joinid,  
t1.flag1, 
t2.flag2, 
case when t1.cond1 is not null then cond1 else 600 end AS cond1 
t1.cond2 as t1cond2,  
t2.cond2 as t2cond2 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.joinid=t2.joinid 
WHERE t1.date IN (date1,date2,date3, etc)